# why TTTAttributedLabel doesn't show last line content after some special symbols on IOS?

Tags: ios, display, tttattributedlabel

This is the correct format on Android:

[image: the correct view style on Android]

But the content of last line doesn't show up on iOS:

[image: the wrong way on IOS]

I tried method below still not work:

```
[_contentLab setText:str afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:^NSMutableAttributedString *(NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString) {
            return mutableAttributedString;
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Github - TTTAttributedLabel issue](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel/issues/658)

Use `TTTAttributedLabel` Version 1.8.1 to avoid truncation issues.

Or better, I would advice trying https://github.com/Krelborn/KILabel which is a project without this issue.

Comment: @Cœur Hi i am facing problem of truncation text clicking.Sometimes it gets clicked sometime the text before truncation text gets clicked.Can you please help me in this.

Comment: Sorry @Aditya, it's best to avoid TTTAttributedLabel.

Comment: @Cœur So any other alternative you need to suggest for this

Comment: @Cœur but truncation property is not there in Krelborn/KILabel

Comment: @Aditya Please open an issue on github or a new question on stackoverflow.